# override the super class methods in wpf Window

Tags: wpf, inheritance, window

I wanna make a customized window base. So I made a custom window which inherits from Window.

For example:

```
public class MyWindowBase : Window
{

...
...

}
```

I wanna override the different Brushes of the super class Window for my own purpose.
In my previous experience, to override methods/properties with no abstract or virtual in the super class need the key word "new".

For example:

```
public new void DoSomething() { ........ base.DoSomething() ....... }
public new string SomeText { get { ... } set {......} }
```

It works in my previous work.

However, in this time of dealing with WPF Window, it doesn't work.

I tried to override the different Brushes of the super class Window as follows:

```
public new Brush BorderBrush  
{
  get { ... }
  set { myBorderBrush = value; base.BorderBrush = null }
}

public new Brush Background 
{
  get { ... }
  set { myBackground = value; base.Backgound = null; }
}

.....
.....
.....
```

I tried the change the value of the above Brushes in MyWindowBase, it just change the value of the super class Window, it doesn't change the value of myBorderBrush and myBackground.

So, how could I override the methods and properties of the super class Window?

Actually, I want to override the base background so that it will be null or transparent forever, but the changed value will be applied on my own custom Background.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try using 'override' instead of 'new'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to set the value, then you can set it using

```
this.BorderBrush = Brushes.Blue;
this.Background = Brushes.Red;
```

If you wish to overwrite the Property Metadata (for things like default value, property changed logic, or validation), you can use [OverrideMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.overridemetadata.aspx)

```
Window.BackgroundProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(MyWindowBase), myPropertyMetadata);
```

If you simply want to add some logic on Changed, you can use a [DependencyPropertyDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dependencypropertydescriptor.addvaluechanged.aspx)

```
var dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(
    Window.BackgroundProperty, typeof(Window));
dpd.AddValueChanged(this.Value, new EventHandler(BackgroundChanged));

private void BackgroundChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do the code here
}
```

And if you're looking to override a Method, and not a Property, then you can use the `override` keyword

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosed(e);
}
```

Comment: what is the "this.Value" in the DependencyPropertyDescriptor?

Comment: I tried both for the property overriding, it doesnt work.
Actually, I want to override the base background so that it will be null or transparent forever, but the changed value will be applied on my own custom Background.